# BSC Chaindata from Binance snapshot

Tags: go-ethereum, bsc

I've been trying to get BSC sycned up in a node that I can use.  I can't seem to get it to start syncing after downloading and extracting the chaindata from Binance, https://docs.binance.org/smart-chain/developer/snapshot.html  If I start it from scratch without the restore, it starts the sync.  WHat could I be doing wrong?  Here's the two logs, one from the terminal and the other from bsc.log.  It seems to get stuck at "Allocated cache and file handles"  I simply ran unzip chaindata.zip, allowing it to overwrite the existing files in chaindata.

Terminal

```
darthg8r@Node:/datadrive2/bscnode/bsc$ geth --config ./config.toml --datadir ./node --pprofaddr 0.0.0.0 --metrics --pprof --verbosity 6 --nousb --cache=8192                            INFO [04-18|06:47:58.072] Starting pprof server                    addr=http://0.0.0.0:6060/debug/pprof
INFO [04-18|06:47:58.072] Starting Geth on Ethereum mainnet...
WARN [04-18|06:47:58.072] Sanitizing cache to Go's GC limits       provided=8192 updated=5337
DEBUG[04-18|06:47:58.072] Sanitizing Go's GC trigger               percent=20
INFO [04-18|06:47:58.072] Enabling metrics collection
INFO [04-18|06:47:58.076] Maximum peer count                       ETH=30 LES=0 total=30
INFO [04-18|06:47:58.076] Smartcard socket not found, disabling    err="stat /run/pcscd/pcscd.comm: no such file or directory"
DEBUG[04-18|06:47:58.076] FS scan times                            list=24.4µs set=700ns diff=1.2µs
TRACE[04-18|06:47:58.076] Started watching keystore folder         path=/datadrive2/bscnode/bsc/node/keystore
```

bsc.log:

```
t=2021-04-18T06:50:30+0000 lvl=info msg="Starting peer-to-peer node" instance=Geth/v1.0.7-46d185b4-20210403/linux-amd64/go1.16.3
t=2021-04-18T06:50:30+0000 lvl=info msg="Allocated trie memory caches" clean="800.00 MiB" dirty="1.30 GiB"
t=2021-04-18T06:50:30+0000 lvl=info msg="Allocated cache and file handles" database=/datadrive2/bscnode/bsc/node/geth/chaindata cache="2.61 GiB" handles=524288
```